# Как передать длину данных по tcp (python)

Tags: python, c#, сокет, клиент-сервер, tcp

Есть сервер на C#, который читает сообщение от клиента вот так:

```
private string ReadMessageWithPrefixLength()
{
    var length = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(BitConverter.ToInt32(ReadBytes(sizeof(int)), 0));
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ReadBytes(length));
}

private byte[] ReadBytes(int size)
{
    var buffer = new byte[size];
    int alreadyReadCount = 0;

    while (size - alreadyReadCount > 0)
    {
        var read = stream.Read(buffer, alreadyReadCount,   size - alreadyReadCount);
        if (read == 0)
            throw new EndOfStreamException();
        
        alreadyReadCount += read;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

И есть клиент на питоне, который должен отправить сначала длину сообщения, а потом и само сообщение:

```
sendMessage = "message"
socket.send(len(sendMessage).to_bytes(2, "big"))
socket.send(sendMessage.encode())
```

Каждый раз, когда я пытаюсь прочитать длину сообщения на сервере, я получаю отрицательное (или наоборот слишком большое) значение. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Вам название функции `ToInt32` о чём-нибудь говорит? `32` бита - это сколько байт? Если что, `int` - это 4 байта, `short` - 2 байта.

Comment: В общем, вы лишних 2 байта из потока читаете и потом 2 байта от настоящей длины и ещё 2 байта уже от самого сообщения вместе слепляете и пытаетесь в `int` преобразовать. Если вы на передающей стороне явно указываете число байт в передаваемой длине, то и на принимающей стороне делайте это явно.

Comment: @CrazyElf оформили бы уже как ответ;)

Comment: @Amgarak А вдруг там ещё где-то косяк? Я просто предполагаю пока ))  Но ладно, оформлю на всякий )

Comment: Когда вместо очевидных [read()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)/[write()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) начинают писать *многабукв* ошибки неизбежны...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в том, что `sizeof(int)` - это `4` байта (на что вам также намекает название функции `ToInt32` - это `32` бита в стандартном `int`). А передаёте вы длину, используя `2` байта в `.to_bytes(2, "big")`.

В общем, вы лишних `2` байта из потока читаете и потом `2` байта от настоящей длины и ещё `2` байта уже от самого сообщения вместе слепляете и пытаетесь в `int` преобразовать. Если уж вы на передающей стороне явно указываете число генерируемых байт в передаваемой длине сообщения, то и на принимающей стороне делайте это также явно: `ReadBytes(2)`. Также можно использовать `ReadBytes(sizeof(short))`, но на мой взгляд лучше делать единообразно.